# How to solve TypeError: Object of type 'Category' is not JSON serializable

Tags: api, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 3 tables (Book,Author,Category)

when I try to get a list of books or authors I have this error: TypeError: Object of type 'Category' is not JSON serializable. I think it's related to the relationship with the category table. Could you please check my models is it structure well or not and how can I solve this issue.

```
__tablename__ = 'author'
id = db.Column(db.Integer().with_variant(Integer, "sqlite"), primary_key=True)
auth_nam = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
gender = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
count_book = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
category=db.relationship('Category', backref='author', lazy=True)

def __init__(self,auth_nam,gender,count_book,category):
  self.auth_nam = auth_nam
  self.gender = gender
  self.count_book = count_book
  self.category = category

def insert(self):
  db.session.add(self)
  db.session.commit()

def update(self):
  db.session.commit()

def delete(self):
  db.session.delete(self)
  db.session.commit()

def format(self):
  return {
    'id': self.id,
    'auth_nam': self.auth_nam,
    'gender': self.gender,
    'count_book': self.count_book,
    'category': self.category
  }

'''
Books
'''
class Book(db.Model):
__tablename__='book'
id = db.Column(db.Integer().with_variant(Integer, "sqlite"), primary_key=True)
book_name=db.Column(db.String,nullable=False)
book_issue=db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False)
category=db.relationship('Category', backref='book', lazy=True)

def __init__(self, book_name, book_issue, category):
   db.create_all()
   self.book_name = book_name
   self.book_issue = book_issue
   self.category = category

def insert(self):
  db.session.add(self)
  db.session.commit()

def update(self):
  db.session.commit()

def delete(self):
  db.session.delete(self)
  db.session.commit()

def format(self):
  return {
    'id': self.id,
    'book_name': self.book_name,
    'book_issue': self.book_issue,
    'category': self.category,
  }


'''
Category
'''
class Category(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'category'
id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(db.String,nullable=False)
book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id'),nullable=False)
author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id'),nullable=False)

def __init__(self, name, book_id, author_id):
  self.name = name
  self.book_id = book_id
  self.author_id = author_id

def insert(self):
  db.session.add(self)
  db.session.commit()

def update(self):
  db.session.commit()

def delete(self):
  db.session.delete(self)
  db.session.commit()

def format(self):
  return {
    'id': self.id,
    'name': self.name,
    'book_id': self.book_id,
    'author_id': self.author_id,
  }


def format(self):
  return {
    'id': self.id,
    'book_name': self.book_name,
    'book_issue': self.book_issue,
    'category': self.category,
  }


'''
Category
'''
class Category(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'category'
id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(db.String,nullable=False)
book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id'),nullable=False)
author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id'),nullable=False)

def __init__(self, name, book_id, author_id):
  self.name = name
  self.book_id = book_id
  self.author_id = author_id

def insert(self):
  db.session.add(self)
  db.session.commit()

def update(self):
  db.session.commit()

def delete(self):
  db.session.delete(self)
  db.session.commit()

def format(self):
  return {
    'id': self.id,
    'name': self.name,
    'book_id': self.book_id,
    'author_id': self.author_id,
  }
```

app.py:

```
 @app.route('/books', methods=['GET'])
  def get_books():
    books = Book.query.all()
    books_formated=[book.format() for book in books]
    return jsonify({
       "success": True,
       "books":books_formated
    })
```

Comment: You have posted category model twice  by mistake or is it a mistake in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have set the `category` as a relationship attribute on Book model, when you call this line in your `Book.format()`:

```py
'category': self.category
```

the `self.category` will return the related `Category` instance, it's a Python object. However, the Python object is not JSON serializable, that's why you got `TypeError: Object of type 'Category' is not JSON serializable.` when `jsonify()` was called.

To solve this, you can either change `self.category` to `'category': [category.name for category in self.category]` (get the string of the category name) or `'category': [category.format() for category in self.category]` (get the dict of the category data). Both string and dict are JSON serializable.

Comment: I edit the models to   ``` def format(self):
    return {
      'id': self.id,
      'book_name': self.book_name,
      'book_issue': self.book_issue,
      'category': self.category.name,
    } 
``` and I get this error :AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: That's because the book can have multiple categories (I didn't notice it before), you can try this: `'category': [category.name for category in self.category]`.